# If amount = number in field then display X value

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

Writing a small php calculator form to display the premium price for an input numeral amount.

unfortunately there is no static formula for the scaling of cost.  So I attempted if/else echo statements for the data ranges

```
if(
    $policyamount<="10000". print("35\.00").
    $policyamount<="15000". print("42\.00").
```

And so on. Am I approaching this correctly, or is this a case of paranoid Monday morning?

Comment: You can learn more about php [here](http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the correct syntax first

```
if($policyamount<=10000)
    echo "35.00";
elseif ($policyamount<=15000)
    echo "42.00";
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd define an array like this:

```
$prices = array(
    10000 => 35,
    15000 => 42,
    // define more price points here
);
```

Then, to display the price:

```
$copy = $prices;
foreach($copy as $k=>$v) {
    if( $policyamount <= $k) {
        echo number_format($v,2);
        break; // end the loop
    }
}
```